# What happened with org.elasticsearch.action.search.MultiSearchResponse?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, multisearchresponse

While upgrading from Spring Boot 2.7.12 to 3.1.3 `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` was implicitly updated to 8.7.1 and now `org.elasticsearch.action.search.MultiSearchResponse` is not found anymore.
I couldn't find anything by googeling.
What happened to it and what do I have to do to make the code run again?

Comment: By upgrading Spring Boot from 2.7 to 3.1, you also "upgraded" your [dependency](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#preface.versions) of Elasticsearch form 7.17 to 8.7. Did you also upgrade your ES server in the process?

Comment: Not yet but I have to check that version. However, this should be independent from the client classes, shouldn't it?

Comment: If you have upgraded Spring Boot but not your ES server, your ES client is now a 8.7 client talking to a 7.17 server, which doesn't work. By the way, [`MultiSearchResponse` is still there](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/8.7/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/search/MultiSearchResponse.java), but I think you probably have the wrong dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I think all necessary dependencies would be imported by Spring Boot itself but it is not! The solution was as easy as putting this into the POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
  <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
  <version>8.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Also make sure to update your ES server so your 8.7.1 client can talk to it